# Custom build steps in Intellij IDEA project

Tags: build, intellij-idea, custom-build-step

I have an **external tool** I need to be executed everytime **Intellij runs Make**. In eclipse I could easily modify the build steps, but I dunno how to achieve that here.

Any ideas?

I expect that it would deal with my resources using external script without having to run it manually before each test run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible via Ant or Maven right now.

For example you can add `build.xml` to the `Ant Build` panel in IntelliJ IDEA, create Ant target that will run your command line tool with the `<exec>` task, right click on this target and set it to run automatically (`Execute on` | `Before Compilation` or `After Compilation`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find any other way to do this either.

Comment: Thanks but missing details: cannot create a build.xml from Ant Build panel, how to set up an <exec> task?, etc... A more detailed answer would really be appreciated.